# Persisting several entities in 1 post (REST API) in Symfony 4 with FosrestBundle

Tags: rest, api, symfony, fosrestbundle

I would like to post several entities in 1 post using fosrestbundle. For now persisting 1 entity works well but I'm not sure how to proceed for several entities.

What I tried for now is to create a **MyEntityCollection class** containing only 1 attribute which is a collection of MyEntity:

```
class MyEntityCollection
{
/*
 * @var Collection
 */
protected $myEntities;

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getMyEntities()
{
    return $this->myEntities;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $myEntities
 */
public function setMyEntities($myEntities): void
{
    $this->myEntities= $myEntities;
}

/**
 * @param MyEntity $myEntity
 * @return MyEntityCollection
 */
public function addMyEntity(MyEntity $myEntity): MyEntityCollection
{
    $this->myEntities->add($myEntity);

    return $this;
}
```

}

I also created a **MyEntityCollectionType formType**:

```
class MyEntityCollectionType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * This function sets the fields of the form
 * @param FormEvent $event the PRE_SET_DATA event
 */
public function setFields(FormEvent $event): void
{
    $form = $event->getForm();

    $form
        ->add('myEntities', EntityType::class, array(
            'required'   => true,
            'multiple' => true,
            'class' => MyEntity::class
        ));
        //->add('myEntities', CollectionType::class, array(
        //    'required'   => true,
        //    'data_class' => MyEntity::class
        //));

}
```

And my **controller action** looks like this:

```
protected function processForm($entity, String $entityTypeClass, $request)
{
    if (empty($entity)) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Entity not found');
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(
        $entityTypeClass,
        $entity
    );
    $form->submit($request->request->all(), false);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $entity;
    }

    return $form;
   }
   /**
    * @Rest\View(statusCode=Response::HTTP_CREATED)
    * @Rest\Post("/myEntity-collection")
    * @param Request $request
    * @return object
    */
    public function postMyEntityCollectionAction(Request $request): object
    {
        $myEntityCollection = new MyEntityCollection();

        return $this->processForm($myEntityCollection, MyEntityCollectionType::class, $request);
    }
```

When I try to post the data to the route I get this error:
*Class "App\Enablon\Checklist\Desktop\Domain\MyEntityCollection" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.*

Just to be clear, I don't want to persist the MyEntityCollection entity, just the several MyEntity, but it seemed to me like a clean way to create the entity class if it needs to be exposed to a post route.

Maybe I'm just not taking the right approach so I'm really open to any suggestion, but it seems to me like a clean way to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is the right way to do it but here is a working case:

I removed the MyEntityCollection entity and it's form type. Instead I do this in my controller:

```
/**
 * @Rest\View(statusCode=Response::HTTP_CREATED)
 * @Rest\Post("/myentity-collection")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return object
 */
public function postMyEntityCollectionAction(Request $request)
{
    $validation = array();
    foreach ($request->request->all() as $myEntityRequest) {
        $validation[] = $this->processForm(new MyEntity(), MyEntityType::class, $myEntityRequest);
    }

    return $validation;
}
```

And I just post an array on MyEntity as a param of my route.

This way the validation errors are easier to understand as they are all in the $validation array returned by the controller.